# Allow incoming WAN traffic while connected to VPN

Tags: linux, router, vpn, iptables, openvpn

I currently have an ASUS router running the latest merlin firmware configured with a couple port forwards, but more importantly, an OpenVPN server that I can connect to while on the road. Everything works as expected until I decided to configure an OpenVPN client on the router as well. As soon as I connect via OpenVPN client, I can no longer access my VPN server or any external ports via the WAN IP from my ISP.

It sounds like it may be routing issue similar to 
[this post](https://superuser.com/questions/819065/allow-incoming-ssh-with-openvpn-client) but have tried the commands with no luck.

Ultimately I would like to have VPN client on my router connected at all times and keep the ability to connect to my OpenVPN server and other open ports.

EDIT: Here is what I tried (based on link above):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vlan2 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1234  
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 1234 -j MARK --set-mark 4321  
ip route add default dev vlan2 via 69.118.144.1 table 3412  
ip rule add fwmark 4312 table 3412
```

Comment: Seems you have a slight terminology mismatch, what your really seem to want is a reverse shell via your openvpn server on the router rather than what you describe which is a pure pass thru.

Comment: Do you have any examples or links where I can start researching?

I can get SSH working with

`ip route add table 50 default via <ISP DEFGW>`
`ip rule add from <ISP WAN IP>/32 table 50`

Comment: Thanks. I will read through it. Just to clarify, clients on my LAN can establish VPN connections directly to VPN provider. And external clients can connect to my OpenVPN server running on my router. I can also establish a VPN connection from my router to my VPN provider. The issue is once I establish the VPN connection from my router to my provider, I can no longer connect external clients to my VPN server on my router (and port forwards on router). If I set up port forwarding via VPN provider, it works via VPN exit IP.

Comment: It seems like the default route from my established VPN takes precedence over the default route for my ISP connection. So traffic coming in through my ISP connection is trying to go back out my VPN. Sorry if my terminology is off or if I am misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: Your terminology is fine, and your diagnosis is also correct. In order to suggest a solution, you should state whether you wish the OpenVPN **client** to apply at all times to all of your LAN clients, or just occasionally to some of them.  And, BTW, you do *not* wish to have a reverse tunnel.

Comment: Thanks MariusMatutiae. I originally wanted my VPN client always connected so all client traffic goes through it but now I am reconsidering since Netflix does not work through it. If I get this working where my VPN client can always be connected and still access externally through ISP WAN IP, I guess my options are route some clients through ISP default gateway or try to find all Netflix server IP ranges and route based on destination.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing [the same issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1152318/policy-routing-for-openvpn-server-client-on-the-same-router) on my OpenWrt router and recently found a simple solution that doesn't involve neither `CONNMARK` nor `MARK`.

1) Create a new routing table and set your WAN gateway as its default route

```
echo "3412 no_vpn_provider" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via <WAN gateway> dev vlan2 table 3412
```

2) This is the crucial part: bind your VPN server to the IP address of the WAN interface using the `local` option in your configuration. If you're using a `.conf`/`.ovpn` file, just add the line

```
local <WAN IP>
```

3) Add this `ip` rule

```
ip rule add from <WAN IP> table 3412 priority 2
```

By default the OpenVPN server doesn't bind to any specific IP, so without 2) this rule won't have any effect.

The routing table as it is should allow clients to connect to the server, but in order to have full functionality you may need to add other routes to it.

Comment: What if your <WAN IP> is dynamic?