# Policy routing for OpenVPN server & client on the same router?

Tags: vpn, routing, iptables, openvpn, iproute2

**PROBLEM**

An OpenVPN server instance (`tun`, `udp`, port `1194`) is set up on a Linux-based router that also runs an OpenVPN client instance (`tun`, `udp`, port `1197`) connecting it to a VPN provider. Both the client and the server instance work fine *individually*. However, clients cannot connect to the VPN server when the VPN client instance is enabled.

I'm sure this happens because the VPN client instance modifies the `main` routing table so that all traffic from (`OUTPUT`) and through (`FORWARD`) the router is routed to the VPN provider. This is the desired default behaviour, but not for connections that are being initiated from the Internet.

Using `iptables` and/or `ip`, how can a routing policy be set up so that all (or at least VPN) connections initiated from the Internet are routed via the standard default gateway (`192.168.1.1`)?

**SETUP**

```
LINUX ROUTER
-----------------------------------------
| LAN if:        br-lan, 192.168.2.1/24 |
| VPN client if: tun0,   10.63.10.6/32  |
| VPN server if: tun1,   10.255.0.1/24  |
| DMZ if:        eth0,   192.168.1.2/24 |
-----------------------------------------
               |
GATEWAY ROUTER |
--------------------------
| DMZ if: 192.168.1.1/24 |
| WAN if: x.x.x.x/x      |
--------------------------
               |
INTERNET       |     VPN CLIENT OF LINUX ROUTER (public IP: y.y.y.y/y)
-----------------    --------------------------------------
|               |----| VPN client if: tun1, 10.255.0.6/24 |
-----------------    --------------------------------------
               |
               |
VPN PROVIDER OF LINUX ROUTER
--------------------------------    
| VPN server if: 10.63.10.1/32 |
--------------------------------
```

As you will notice we're in a double NAT situation here. As uncomfortable as it may be *this is not the problem*, since clients *can* connect when the VPN client instance is disabled.

With the VPN client and server instances enabled, this is the `main` routing table, as given by `ip route list table main`:

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.63.10.5 dev tun0   #added by VPN client instance
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static 
10.63.10.1 via 10.63.10.5 dev tun0   #added by VPN client instance
10.63.10.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.63.10.6   #added by VPN client instance
10.255.0.0/24 via 10.255.0.2 dev tun1 
10.255.0.2 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.255.0.1 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.63.10.5 dev tun0   #added by VPN client instance
178.162.199.211 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0   #added by VPN client instance
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2 
192.168.2.0/24 dev br-lan  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.1
```

and these are the ip rules, as given by `ip rule list`:

```
0:  from all lookup 128   #a non-existent table
1:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default   #empty table
```

**ATTEMPTS**

First of all I've built a `no_vpn_provider` routing table (`echo "2 no_vpn_provider" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables`), an exact copy of the `main` table without the VPN client instance modifications. `ip route list table no_vpn_provider` shows

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static 
10.255.0.0/24 via 10.255.0.2 dev tun1 
10.255.0.2 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.255.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2 
192.168.2.0/24 dev br-lan  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.1
```

**1)** I tried these simple `ip` rules

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.2 table no_vpn_provider priority 2
ip rule add from 10.255.0.1 table no_vpn_provider priority 3
```

where `192.168.1.2` and `10.255.0.1` are the IP addresses of the external interface `eth0` and of the VPN server interface `tun1` respectively.

I also tried `from all iif eth0` and `from all iif tun1` instead of `from 192.168.1.2` and `from 10.255.0.1`.

**2)** I tried marking with `0x1` new *connections* (the `conntrack` module is installed) to interfaces `eth0` and `tun1`

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -i eth0 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -i tun1 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 0x1
```

and adding this rule to make marked connections use the new routing table

```
ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table no_vpn_provider priority 2
```

**3)** I tried marking outgoing *packets* from the VPN server port `1194`

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 1194 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1194 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1   # just in case
```

and using the same rule

```
ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table no_vpn_provider priority 2
```

I've also tried 2) and 3) with different marks and with inserting (`-I`) instead of appending (`-A`). Suspecting my firewall wasn't marking at all I tested

```
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table no_vpn_provider priority 2
```

but, as expected, packets from my LAN didn't get forwarded to the VPN provider.

**4)** The only thing that *works* so far is this ugly rule

```
ip rule add from all to y.y.y.y/y table no_vpn_provider priority 2
```

where y.y.y.y/y is the public IP address of the client trying to connect: this is of course a terrible solution, because the clients are not going to connect always from the same network.

Comment: @AdamSilenko I've tried to rephrase the question in a clearer way and with more details. see if you can give me some input now. try to be more specific: what do you think is not working about my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make all packets sent by an interface with IP address `192.168.1.2` use a custom routing table `no_vpn_provider`, you can simply use

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.2 table no_vpn_provider priority 2
```

as I did in attempt 1). The problem is that by default an OpenVPN server doesn't bind to any specific IP address, so the above rule won't have any effect (https://serverfault.com/a/228258).

To bind your OpenVPN server to the IP address `192.168.1.2`, just add this line to its configuration file and you're good to go

```
local 192.168.1.2
```

**NOTE** If you create the rule and the custom routing table with `ip`, they will be erased every time you reboot the router. Depending on your `openvpn` configuration, the custom routing table may also get modified every time you restart `openvpn`. You can write scripts that re-create the rule and the custom routing table whenever it's needed.

Comment: While this solved my problem, it would still be nice to understand why the marking attempts 2) and 3) didn't work.